# Get Data from Controls created by listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Hello and thanks for taking your time and reading this question.

**My Database table:**
[image]

**My Asp Code:**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnReturn" Text="Return to Questions" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstQuestion">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h1><%# Eval("Title") %></h1>
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" id="rblAnswers">
            <asp:ListItem Text="yes"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="no"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Maybe"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttest"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btntest" Text="Get Result" OnClick="btntest_Click" />
```

**The output in the browser**

[image]

What I want to achive is: If the User press the *btntest* and the page looks like the one above. A simple response.write() *(to start with)* shall write the : no - Coment1 - yes - Coment 2.

Basic it write what has been select and coments if something is typed.

I hope you understand and sorry for my english.

Comment: Writes it to the database? I am not quite sure what you are trying ot do.

Comment: No just simple write the values that has been selected in a response.write();

Comment: Can't you just use HttpResponse.Write() in the button Click event? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Problem i dont know how to get the values from the different text box and radiobuttonlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use find control to reference the controls inside the ListView. However if the controls you want to access are part of the ListView ItemTemplate, then you need to iterate through each item and find the controls for that item.

I wrote this without an IDE, it should be something like this:

```
//Iterate through the rows of the List View
foreach (item ListViewItem in lstView.Items)
{
     //If the control is a data item
     if (item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem)
     {
          RadioButtonList  rbl = item.FindControl("rblAnswers") as RadioButtonList;
          if(rbl != null)
          {
          //do something
          }

          TextBox tb = item.FindControl("txttest") as TextBox;
          if(tb != null)
          {
          //do something    
          }
     }
}
```